# What is the purpose of using session in WCF

Tags: wcf, session

i read a write up and they said `WCF does support sessions yes; but they are not like ASP.NET sessions. Sessions are there to deliver messages in order`

so i do not understand what session does in wcf. in asp.net many people authenticate user and store some value in session and later check for every secure page access that the value is available in that session variable or not?

if not then redirect user to login page. but i like to understand what session does in wcf? if session is not enable in wcf then what will not be possible.

please explain with small example as a result i can understand. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little in common between WCF session and ASP.Net session state - the differences are clearly highlighted in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx). Basically, ASP.Net sessions revolve around identification of the user's interaction with a web site, and allow for storage of `Session State` which is associated with this user session.

A WCF session retains state across multiple calls, e.g. the server will be able to resume a conversation with state information from the previous method calls made by the same session. There is no out-of-the-box persistence for state in a WCF session, and typically, WCF sessions will be of shorter duration than an ASP.Net session.

WCF Session methods invoked during the Session may need to be in a specific order (`IsInitiating`, `IsTerminating`).

The calculator example is a good one:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ICalculatorSession
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true, IsInitiating=true, IsTerminating=false)]
    void Clear();
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void AddTo(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void SubtractFrom(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void MultiplyBy(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void DivideBy(double n);
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    double Equals();
}
```

From the above interface:

- The client MUST initiate a session by calling `Clear()` (i.e. it can't start doing any calcs until this method is called)
- The client can then call any number of `DivideBy`, `MultiplyBy`, `SubtractFrom`, `AddTo` methods. At all points, the server will remember the previous state, i.e. the result of the previous calculations, like the register in a calculator.
- The client calls `Equals` to get a final result, which also ends the Session.

**Edit**
I've uploaded a sample to [GitHub](http://github.com/nonnb/WcfSessionSample) here, with client and server bits, for VS2010.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can u give me small code which proof that service can remember the result of previous state when session is enable.

Comment: when session is not implemented then IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true these attribute make any sense?

Comment: (Edit) AFAIK the attributes IsInitiating and IsTerminating are meaningless unless used in conjunction with SessionMode=SessionMode.Required / Allowed AND a Session based binding. Code sample - I'll see what I can do.

Comment: thanks....please provide code sample which proof that service can remember the result of previous state when session is enable.

Comment: I've uploaded a sample to [Github](http://github.com/nonnb/WcfSessionSample). Main service implementation is [here](https://github.com/nonnb/WcfSessionSample/blob/master/WcfLibrary1/SOCalculator.svc.cs). Note the need for a session-enabled binding like `wsHttpBinding`