# InstanceContextMode.PerSession not working

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I m using InstanceContextMode.PerSession in wshttpbinding as mentioned in below code but it seems not working,since my count is not increasing.

Please advice.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ITransService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
        int Insert(int userId);

        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        [OperationContract]
        int Update();

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class TransService : ITransService
    {
        public int count = 0;
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public int Insert(int userId)
        {
            count = count+1;
            return count;
        }

        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public int Update()
        {
            count = count++;
            return count;
        }
    }
```

**Client Call ---**

```
using (TransactionScope tranScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    TransServiceClient obj = new TransServiceClient();
                    var a= obj.Insert(123);
                    var b = obj.Insert(123);
                    var c = obj.Update();

                    tranScope.Complete();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>In addition to marking the interface as `(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)`, you'll also need to define which methods on the interface [initiate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isinitiating(v=vs.110).aspx) the session, like so: e.g. if Just Insert initiates the session:    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]    int Insert(int userId); There's an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21479312/314291)</del>

*(No, `IsInitiating = true` is the default in any event)*

As per the extended commentary, a trial and error approach eventually yielded that `TransactionFlow` prevents `SessionMode` from working correctly. I cannot currently find a definitive reference on this - the closest to date [is this](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=WCF+incompatible+SessionMode+TransactionFlow&source=bl&ots=CixwJwKZQx&sig=SsxL7kNeWdmZfqqhL4lPpNl3zxw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ngmbVN__McX1UL_0g7AL&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=WCF%20incompatible%20SessionMode%20TransactionFlow&f=false). Logically, sessions can last for far longer durations than Transactions (and given that Transactions could hold locks on database and queue resources) there is some logic.

The solution was to remove `TransactionFlow`.

**Edit**

For those looking to combine both `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` and `TransactionFlow`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649719/how-to-simultaneously-implement-session-and-transaction-flow-in-wcf)

Comment: I added below line & updated my service reference but no luck [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]

Comment: IsInitiating goes into the interface - I made a mistake with the initial post? You can also try and force it by changing `SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed` to `SessionMode.Required`

Comment: I have updated the same in my code & updated the client service reference too but still i an having same issue.i don't know what mistake i am doing in this code.

Comment: yes you are right +1 ,after removing the TransactioFlow this is working fine.but can you please help me out with some links or your answer that why this is incompatable?

Comment: @user1721131 After some trial and error, I was eventually able to get both Session and Transaction flow working simultaneously - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649719/how-to-simultaneously-implement-session-and-transaction-flow-in-wcf). This doesn't look well documented, in MSDN, FWR.