# How to simultaneously implement Session and Transaction Flow in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

While attempting to answer a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640768/instancecontextmode-persession-not-working/27640806#27640806), it became apparant that the neither myself or the OP could simultaneously build a WCF service which was both `Session` and `TransactionFlow` enabled - the only solution I could offer was to remove `TransactionFlow` in order to get the WCF Session instancing working.

Although logically Session durations could conceivably outlive Transactions (bearing in mind that `TransactionFlow` could mean that transactions are holding precious server resources like Database locks, Messaging Queues and transactional file systems), I can't find a definitive reference either way confirming or rejecting the possiblility to concurrently implementing both features.

So my question is : How can I get both `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession` and `TransactionFlow` working concurrently in WCF?

What was tried:

**ITransactionService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ITransactionService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    int Start(int userId);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    int Finish(int userId);
}
```

**TransactionService.svc.cs**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService
{
    public int count = 0;

    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public int Start(int userId)
    {
        Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current != null, "No Transaction!");
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }

    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public int Finish(int userId)
    {
        Debug.Assert(Transaction.Current != null, "No Transaction!");
        Debug.Assert(count > 0, "No Session!");
        return count;
    }
```

**Client.cs**

```
  using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
  using (var svc = new TransactionServiceClient())
  {
      svc.Start(0);
      svc.Finish(0);
      ts.Complete();
  }
```

**Service web.config**

```
  <services>
      <service name="WcfLibrary1.TransactionService">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="WcfLibrary1.ITransactionService">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
          </endpoint>
      </service>
  </services>
   <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding transactionFlow="true"/>
       </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <protocolMapping>
       <remove scheme="http" />
       <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="transactionFlowEnabled"/>
   </protocolMapping>
```

**Client web.config**

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionService" transactionFlow="true" />
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:65171/TransactionService.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionService"
        contract="TransactionService.ITransactionService" name="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionService">
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, it seems it is possible. The issue appears to be that the default behaviour of `TransactionFlow` [applies the following default settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx):

- On the class' [ServiceBehavior attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.releaseserviceinstanceontransactioncomplete(v=vs.110).aspx)  - `ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = true`
- On the methods' [OperationContract attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionautocomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) - `TransactionAutoComplete = true`

Which when used in conjunction with each other, will cause the instance of the service to be released, thus destroying any state retained in an existing Session.

Disabling either of these options will keep the Service instance alive for the duration of the Session, and so allowing `TransactionFlow` and `Session` to be used simultaneously:

i.e. on the `ServiceContract`:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ITransactionService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    int Start(int userId);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    int Finish(int userId);
}
```

Either change to this on the Service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
                 ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService
{
```

Or, on the Operation:

```
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, 
                       TransactionAutoComplete = false)]
    public int Start(int userId)
    {
```